# UnicodeEndcodeError - utf-8 encoding in python-crfsuite (pycrfsuite)

Tags: python, unicode, nlp

EDITED: I've updated my traceback below

I know this kind of problems has been asked for many times, but I have been struggling to this issue 2 days and still can't figure a solution.
Here the case: I'm using `pycrfsuite` (a python implementation of CRF), and this snippets raise `UnicodeEncodeError`.

```
 trainer = pycrfsuite.Trainer(verbose=True)
 for xseq, yseq in zip(X_train, y_train):
    trainer.append(xseq, yseq)
```

Error ...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):  
File "/home/enamoria/Dropbox/NLP/POS-tagger/MyTagger/V2_CRF/src/pos-tag/pos-tag.py", line 46, in <module>
     trainer.append(xseq, yseq)
File "pycrfsuite/_pycrfsuite.pyx", line 312, in pycrfsuite._pycrfsuite.BaseTrainer.append
File "stringsource", line 48, in vector.from_py.__pyx_convert_vector_from_py_std_3a__3a_string
File "stringsource", line 15, in string.from_py.__pyx_convert_string_from_py_std__in_string
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\u201d' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

`\u201d` is the *closing double quote* ***”*** in `utf8` encoding. This exception was also raised for `\u201c` (*opening double quote*) and `\u2026` (*ellipsis* IIRC)

FYI, `X_train` and `y_train` is a features representation of a text and its corresponding labels, which I read from a file. I've try using `encoding='utf8', errors='ignore'` but the error still there

```
 for file in filelist:
        with open(self.datapath + "/" + file, "r", encoding='utf8', errors='ignore') as f:
            raw_text = [(line.strip("\n").strip(" ").replace("   ", " ").replace("  ", " ")).split(" ") for line in f.readlines() if line != '\n']
            data.extend(raw_text)
```

My question is: Is `pycrfsuite` only support `ascii` encoding? If so, is there any workaround available for me? My data is Vietnamese which ascii can't represent, and a new crf library is the last thing I want

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't know `pycrf`, but if it actually only supports ASCII, then you need to convert your data to ASCII. Depending on how much you value the non-ASCII characters, you can either use some transliteration library like [Unidecode](https://pypi.org/project/Unidecode/), or use brutal force by reading the data files with `encoding='ascii', errors='replace'` or `errors='ignore'`, which will replace them with `'?'` or remove them entirely.

Comment: Thanks for your comment!  
Unfortunately,  my data is Vietnamese, which ascii can't represent. Using 'errors='ignore'' do make the problem goes away, but the input will look ridiculous.

Comment: What version of Python are you using? And which version of pycrfsuite?

Comment: Also, please include the full traceback, to show where exactly the UnicodeError is produced.

Comment: I've updated my post. I'm using python 3.5.2, pycrfsuite 0.9.5

Comment: Hi, have you solved this "ascii" problem? It seems this error remain in the latest version of sklearn-crfsuite with python 3.6+ ...

Comment: If you figured this out please share the solution since I can reproduce the error with python 3.8 and arabic text

Answer (score 0):

The pycrfsuite docs don't mention what their Unicode support is for feature values and keys.
I can't tell from the examples either, as it isn't clear to me if they are Python 2 or 3.
Also, I don't know enough about Cython to give you a definite answer by reading the source.

In any case, I suggest you try two things:

1. Just encode the keys yourself before you pass them to the library. If the values are strings too, encode them as well. Maybe the library is happy to accept `bytes` objects.
2. If that doesn't work (because it really wants to have ASCII), use some ASCII encoding, eg. use `urlencode` or call Python's `ascii()` built-in function on the string. The latter will encode `'can’t'` to `"'can\\u2019t'"`, with backslash escapes and quotes. It doesn't really matter, since the classifier doesn't care about how the feature keys look, as long as the same input produces the same feature key.

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Before the `for` loop you can use the `encode('utf-8')` method for each string element on `xseq` and `yseq`.

One element of my `xseq` that make me problems looks like this now `[b'nxtletter=<\xc3\xad']`

This is my code

```py
def sent2features(data):
    return [extractFeatures(sent) for sent in data]

def sent2labels(data):
    return [extractLabels(sent) for sent in data]

X_train = sent2features(train_data)
Y_train = sent2labels(train_data)

for xseq, yseq in zip(X_train, Y_train):
    trainer.append(xseq, yseq)
```

The encoding lines on `extractFeatures` and `extractLabels` functions looks like this

```py
def extractFeatures(sent):
    feature_list = []
    for sent in sents:
       word_len = len(sent)
       for letter in sent:
           .
           .  # Here I define my features list
           .
           feature_list.append([f.encode('utf-8') for f in features])  # Here add encoding for pysrfsuite
    return feature_list

def extractLabels(sent):
    labels = []
    for word in sent:
        for letter in word:
            labels.append(letter[2].encode('utf-8')) # Here add encoding for pysrfsuite
    return labels
```

Maybe works for you. Good luck!

Comment: It will be helpful if you include an edited code block and if possible, the expected output

Comment: Thanks for comment. I'm new answering here :)